# Can't run android from server

Tags: android, macos, ionic-framework, configuration

I have android sdk installed from homebrew in iMac and I need to run an ionic app. Locally it works fine. But when I `ionic run android` from file server i got this:

```
iMac-de-Iwwa:ClickNoticias hugo$ ionic run android
cordova-custom-config: Skipping auto-restore of config file backup(s)
Running command: "/Volumes/Sites/apps/Click Notícias/ClickNoticias/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js" "/Volumes/Sites/apps/Click Notícias/ClickNoticias"
add to body class: platform-android
cordova-custom-config: Applied custom config from config.xml to /Volumes/Sites/apps/Click Notícias/ClickNoticias/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
Observed package id '..;..;..;var;lib;android-sdk;samples;android-19' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/samples/android-19' (Expected '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/../../../var/lib/android-sdk/samples/android-19')
Observed package id '..;..;..;var;lib;android-sdk;samples;android-20' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/samples/android-20' (Expected '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/../../../var/lib/android-sdk/samples/android-20')
Observed package id '..;..;..;var;lib;android-sdk;samples;android-21' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/samples/android-21' (Expected '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/../../../var/lib/android-sdk/samples/android-21')
Observed package id '..;..;..;var;lib;android-sdk;samples;android-22' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/samples/android-22' (Expected '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/../../../var/lib/android-sdk/samples/android-22')
Observed package id '..;..;..;var;lib;android-sdk;samples;android-23' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/samples/android-23' (Expected '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/../../../var/lib/android-sdk/samples/android-23')
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Operation not supported
> Operation not supported

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.025 secs
Error: /Volumes/Sites/apps/Click Notícias/ClickNoticias/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Operation not supported
> Operation not supported

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I read the error and i've seen this:

`Observed package id '..;..;..;var;lib;android-sdk;samples;android-19' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/samples/android-19' (Expected '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/../../../var/lib/android-sdk/samples/android-19')`

I actually made a copy of android-sdk to `/usr/var/lib/android-sdk` just for testing. But it doesn't works.

Someone have any idea of how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem before, and it essentially means that your Android Home directory wasn't set properly.